# Ajax return, json data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using a ajax request with the following call to function.

```
var test = initBuild(id);
    test.success(function (data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

The `data` being returned looks like

```
{"built_when":{"id":"43701","clientId":"245","name":"Big Ass Gallery","productId":"0","desc":null,"bgColor":"#000000","fontColor":"ffffff","sort":"43701","clientRef":"205","isFeatured":"0","created":"1367356190","views":"0","finish":"0","isArchive":"0","showMailShare":"0","hardPageFlip":"0","hardCoverFlip":"0","isTemp":"0","agreement":"0","maxChange":"0","countChange":"0","verticalFlip":"0","musicSwitch":"0","showFbShare":"0","twitter":null,"email":"0","pageHeight":"1000","pageWidth":"1391"}}
```

I am trying to access by data.built_when.id, but it's returning null. What am I missing on this one.

Thanks

Comment: Have you parsed the data into an object? Try `var dataObject = JSON.parse(data)` if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure about the return type of the ajax request to be always `json` then you can set  `dataType: 'json'` to the ajax option.

Ex:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '',
    dataType: 'json',
    ....
})
```

Answer (score 2):

It's being returned as a string.  Use `data = $.parseJSON(data);` to convert it to JS constructs.  Alternatively, you could set the `Content-type: application/json` header on the server side when you emit the JSON

Comment: or set `dataType: 'json'` in the ajax option

Comment: @Explosion Pills -- thanks for the answer. Works perfectly. Added the dataType to the function and took care of it that way. should have posted the function.